# Stanford NER: extracting separate lists of entities?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I can get a string annotated with Named Entities with the following code.

```
String NEString =  classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(fileContents)
```

I'm wondering if there is any method to call so that I can get separate entities (PERSON, ORGANIZATION, LOCATIOIN) lists in the file, that way I don't have to parse the retrieved string with the above method to get the entity lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanes way to run the classification is:

```
List<Triple<String,Integer,Integer>> out = classifier.classifyToCharacterOffsets(text);
triple.first(): entity type
triple.second(): start position
triple.third(): end position
```

It groups consequent entities and returns the start and end position of entities.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there are 3 ways to get annotated string:

1) `classifier.classifyToString(" ")`

2) `classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(" ")`

3) `classifier.classifyToString(" ", "xml", true)`

The first one is the easiest to seperate. Unfortunately, there isn't any method as you wish.